# Can / should I add the box-shadow's size to the element's total size?

Tags: css, anchor, box-shadow

I know it doesn't by default, but I'm trying to force it to.

I'm building a button-like anchor that has a solid box-shadow (no blur) to create the illusion of depth, and when hovered it reacts.

Only problem is that it reacts only when the cursor is above the anchor itself, and since it moves a few pixels when hovered, depending on how close is the cursor to the edge, it causes the anchor to flicker.

Is it possible to order the shadow to be included in the element's total size? And I know it's kind of bothersome that a button misbehaves in this way, but is it terrible coding? I realize it's kind of a design question, but I'm after the code, really.

**TLDR: my anchor flickers when hovered too close to the edge. alternatives?**

The code is working, but I'll paste it anyway.

Here's the code:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  /*center*/
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #71e2ff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #34d6ff, 0 2px #34d6ff, 0 3px #34d6ff, 0 4px #34d6ff;
}
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px #34d6ff, 0 2px #34d6ff, 0 3px #34d6ff, 0 4px #34d6ff, 0 5px #34d6ff, 0 6px #34d6ff;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px #34d6ff, 0 2px #34d6ff;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
 <a class="btn" href="#">suscribe</a>
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks Paulie_D, worked like a charm! Pseudo element with absolute position stretched in all directions was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't include a box-shadow in the height/width calculations but you can increase the *click / hover area* by using a pseudo-element which is sized to include the box-shadow.

From [**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/123-if-it-moves-when-you-click-make-something-stick/)

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4e68c7;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891, 0px 1px 1px #3852b1, 2px 1px 1px #203891, 1px 2px 1px #3852b1, 3px 2px 1px #203891, 2px 3px 1px #3852b1, 4px 3px 1px #203891, 3px 4px 1px #3852b1, 5px 4px 1px #203891, 4px 5px 1px #3852b1, 6px 5px 1px #203891;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  position: relative;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: #3d57b4;
}
button:hover,
button:active {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891, 0px 1px 1px #3852b1, 2px 1px 1px #203891, 1px 2px 1px #3852b1, 3px 2px 1px #203891;
  -moz-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  -ms-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}
button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  /* for demo */
}
button:hover::after,
button:active:after {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
#message {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<button>A Button</button>
```